# How to install perl modules on macos when cc can't handle stdlib.h

Tags: xcode, macos, perl, cpan, cc

So in trying to install various Perl modules, including e.g. Module::Build, I get errors that stem from stdlib.h, like:

```
In file included from lib/Simple.xs:2:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.2/lib/perl5/5.28.2/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE/perl.h:819:
/usr/include/stdlib.h:147:38: error: expected ')'
           size_t __width, int (* _Nonnull __compar)(const void *, const void *));
                                           ^
/usr/include/stdlib.h:147:26: note: to match this '('
            size_t __width, int (* _Nonnull __compar)(const void *, const void *));
                                ^
```

(There are many more errors, but that appears to be the first and seems like a representative and hopefully illustrative sample.)

I believe these errors are because my installation of cc and the included library don't match, but I'm not a c programmer and have no idea how to debug this. Also, the point here is to install perl modules, not learn C, so I am hopeful that some solution exists that does not involve debugging C.

```
Perl: 5.28.2
macOS: 10.13.6
cc -v: Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
  Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0
  Thread model: posix
```

Comment: What does the documentation of the module you are installing say which operating systems it is compatible with? Which compilers? Are you using one of those operating systems? Are you using one of those compilers?

Comment: Jörg W Mittag - as is common with perl modules, it makes no mention of compatibility with particular operating systems or compilers; in general, I think it is assumed that Perl Modules Just Work. (In Module::Build's particular case, it can be confusing because it is used for installing other modules, and so it talks about installation in that sense. Presumably once it is installed, it would be used to install the other modules I actually care about using, such as Math::Random.)

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag, The error is coming from stdlib.h. This problem has nothing to do with Perl or any Perl module

Comment: @ikegami: the OP is installing a Perl module. I am not intimately familiar with how the Perl module system works, but I am pretty sure that either the Perl module system or the Perl module itself controls the installation process, including which compiler to use. If the Perl module (system) decides to use a compiler that is not compatible with the rest of the system, then you will get an error like this.

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag, The command line executed is output to the screen. It's built from the variables output by `perl -V:'cc.*'`. The compiler used should be the same one that was used to build Perl itself (but you know how distros like to mangle things...)

Comment: @Vynce, I don't know why you mention Module::Build. Math::Random doesn't use Module::Build, and Math::Random has no dependencies. (Also, Module::Build doesn't have a C component, though one of its dependencies might.)

Comment: Re "*Presumably once it is installed, it would be used to install the other modules I actually care about using*", Each modules provides an installation script, and these scripts largely use ExtUtils::MakeMaker (bundled with Perl) or Module::Build (not bundled with Perl) to install the module.

Comment: @ikegami : *shrug* I can't speak to that. I can only say that during debugging, i came across logs that said I couldn't install `Module::Build`, among many other things, and that the text posted above is from attempting to install Module::Build. Other things in the logs that made it look like that was a root dependency past which I could not proceed. Once it worked, so did everything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although Apple's App Store did not list XCode in the list of updates I needed, I tried installing the most recent version -- well, the most recent version it would allow for my OS -- and when I had finished, I had a new version of `cc` that worked.